# Two packages conflict in AppDelegate.m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I use https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin and https://github.com/luisfcofv/react-native-deep-linking packages in my project. I did not solve the following part of the AppDelegate.m file so that the packages can work.

For this react-native-google-signin

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RNGoogleSignin application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

For this react-native-deep-linking

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

I'm not good at Objective-C. How do I return RNGoogleSignin and RCTLinkingManager with a single function?

Answer (score 6):

Since both methods return a BOOL, you could try something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
   BOOL success = [RNGoogleSignin application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) 
   if (!success)
       success = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

   return success;
}
```

updated based on comments from @rmaddy.

Comment: You want `||`, not `&&` since you want to return YES if either one worked. Simply do `return signin || linkingManager;`.

Comment: It might also make sense to only try the second if the first doesn't succeed.

Comment: Your update all wrong now. You don't set `success` based on the 1st attempt and you are only making the 2nd attempt if the 1st succeeds. You should only make the 2nd attempt if the 1st fails.

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks for your comments, hope this is correct now.